# When we create the .rec file, do the class ids in the .lst file have to be consecutive and start from 0?

Tags: mxnet

If all the images come from 3 classes, can the set of class ids we put into the second column of the .lst file be {101, 280, 76}? Or it has to be consecutive integers like {5,6,7}, or even more strict, has to be {0,1,2} ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no requirements on label values. For your case, {101, 280, 76} should be fine.